# How to highlight google markers when we scroll horizontal list in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, jquery-animate, highlight

How to highlight google marker when we scroll list horizontal.

i want the same functionality that we have in google maps app when we search any place or shop in app

> [check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOpzY.jpg)

so how can we achieve this functionality in flutter